# Suggestions for file and data tranforms using SQL Query Results to manipulate existing PDF Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, etl

Apologies if something similar to the question I'm asking has already been addressed. I'm not even sure how to best frame my question but I haven't been able to find any posts that are obviously germane. I'm hoping someone has some experience with this and might be willing to offer some suggestions. My company has already contracted to have the bulk of our database converted to HTML for ETL purposes and we simply can't afford to double the already barely-manageable costs of this project by adding this additional requirement to the scope.

We have a SQL database from an EMR software vendor that our company has now left. Due to recent economic factors, we just just can't afford to stay with them any longer. When we left this ex-vendor begrudgingly provided us with a backup copy of our SQL database along with copies of all the scanned images our users have uploaded via their application GUI over the years. I was told they stored the uploads as BLOB data but it turns out not. They weren't actually storing the files in the database at all. Instead, they moved the image to a storage location and wrote the ID, DocType, Filename, DirPath and other document information to the Document table of the DB. It makes sense but leaves us in a bind. Mainly because the filename appears to have been randomly generated at upload. So we now have 50,000 image files with unintelligible filenames stored in a date-based folder structure with no way to correlate any of them with the patients to whom they belong. A couple of examples are as follows:

- /root/2020/05102019/69353829-e46b-47e7-ab56-a1762424f0dd.pdf
- /root/2014/09282017/385ba21d-e108-4cbb-9287-91110c16edb0.jpg

I compiled a list of attribs so I can make any of them available to the transform. I pulled:

```
        SELECT * FROM document d
          JOIN patients p ON d.PatientId = p.pid
          JOIN users u ON d.PatientId = u.uid
        WHERE u.UserType = '3' AND d.fileformat is NOT NULL AND d.dirpath LIKE 'm%'
        ORDER BY u.ulname;
```

This gave me all patient and document attribs resulting in a list with 197 columns. The challenge is the new EMR vendor can only import these files if all the files for each patient are in a dedicated folder at the patient level so I need the files in a new folder structure. I am trying to do it without abandoning things like PatientID, Scan Date, Description (the customName column), Scanned By, and a possibly a couple other points.

I'll probably end up making the file name something like a concat of customName+docID for identification purposes. Then I'll just need to get the files in something like a /Patient/Docs.extension folder structure.

I went ahead and flattened all the files into a single folder figuring that would make it easier to manipulate. I batched them out like so:

```
        md "D:\OneDrive\Documents\Assets\eClinicalworks\PID\FTP\mobiledoc\Documents\All\"
        cd /d "D:\OneDrive\Documents\Assets\eClinicalworks\PID\FTP\mobiledoc\Documents\"
        for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "D:\OneDrive\Documents\Assets\eClinicalworks\PID\FTP\mobiledoc\Documents\All\"
```

Now I have them all together.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v5vU.jpg)

I still have to figure out how to get them into the new folder structure by patient though.

Just to have it mentioned, I was originally considering using SQL so I could recreate the files and assign the desired attribs as file attribs in one step.

To answer the question asked about the HTML conversion, we have tons of Progress Notes, Doctors Notes, Prescriptions, etc in the database. The only way to get them to the new EMR is to export them to HTML and group them at the patient level so the new vendor can import them.

Honestly, after having to wrestle with all this garbage, I would prefer to avoid this situation in the future by refusing to upload them to the new EMR at all. Instead, just put all these documents on OUR file server and give the new EMR a hyper-link to insert into each patient's patient record that would open all the patient files. The new EMR is browser-based so it could be feasible but I doubt I'll be able to get them to write files to our file server moving forward so doing so would likely just end up making the end-user experience more disjointed.

Comment: How would you determine "*useful filenames*"? Also "*converting database to HTML*" sounds extremely strange.

Comment: So you want to go through the old sql db Documents table, find the correlating image and rename it to something more meaningful?

Comment: What will the new vendor import them into? A DB? I'd be thinking about turning you existing db into an XML file that they can already process. Don't leave it to them; they'll break it and not care. Ask them for their file import formats spec

Comment: Each patient should have a unique identifier in the system somewhere, whether that is an int or a guid doesn’t really matter too much.  The unique identifier should NOT be their name or SSN.  Names changes and SSN can be entered incorrect and shouldn’t be spread all over the places.

Comment: Good points and questions. Thank you all very much. I'll update the question with explanations and clarifications shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't  think your contractors did anything wrong tbh. Taking uploaded files with all their problem characters/duplicated names (got more than one patient called JohnSmith.jpg?) etc and renaming them to a GUID so they can coexist alongside other images without overwriting them is a) sensible and b) what I would do.

I also wouldn't store images inside a database as then the only thing you can do with them is get them out again; something you have to do every time you want to do anything with them. Being able to map an images folder to a url on your web server and then send html using just the file name means that the web server can sever the image without having to pull it out of the db; the db doesn't have to involve itself in pointless IO.

The way to correlate these images with the patients to whom they belong is done by the database. Somewhere else in the db structure will be eg a Patient record with a DocumentId column that links to this document record or a PatientDocuments table that has PatientId/DocumentId pairs.

If there is not, then storing the document bytes in the db won't have helped relate them to the patient, because this relation is not about where the bytes of an image are, it's about what other data was stored to make for a usable system. As it stands your thoughts on the matter, of uploading tens of thousands of images into a db just so you can... er.. get them all out again, would seem to indicate you haven't yet fully grasped the reasons behind why your contractors did what they did.

Because you're under the impression that you can do this, you seem to know how the db relates a document to a patient (if it doesn't then your proposed process will fail) and as such you can arrange for a suitable renaming process without needing to move the image data anywhere. In essence, you're failing to see that a file system storing file data against unique paths is no different to a database table storing file data against unique ids. Your database tables for documents clearly thus links to your file system/file system can be viewed as an extension to the documents table. You need the other tables in the db to make sense of the files, but you need the other tables in a db to make sense of any table in a db. These are key concepts of modelling related data

I don't recommend you undertake the process you propose, but I'm sure that won't dissuade. Consider then (because you didn't really post any details we can work with) this assumed scenario:

```
Patients
Name,DocumentId
John Smith,1
Jane Doe,2

Documents
Id,FilePath
1,'/root/2020/05102019/69353829-e46b-47e7-ab56-a1762424f0dd.pdf'
2,'/root/2014/09282017/385ba21d-e108-4cbb-9287-91110c16edb0.jpg'

SELECT CONCAT('REN ', d.filePath, ' "',  p.Name, RIGHT(d.filePath, 4), '"') 
FROM
  Patients p 
  INNER JOIN Documents d ON p.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
```

The results of the query will essentially be a batch file full of rename commands that renames all the files into a single folder, organized by patient name.

And now all your multiple patients with the same names will overwrite each other and everything will end up in a mess

It also makes my point for me about "don't store files in the db" - look how easy it is to manipulate files when they're in a file system, using existing commands that understand filesystems and files and do things like rename files, or extract exif data, rotate, resize and print... if all those images were in your db the only thing you could do with them, is get them out again; sqlserver cannot rotate, resize, print etc BLOB data but there are thousands of tools out there that understand files and can convert them - those tools cannot understand your db so putting files into a db saddles you with the problem that they become useless until dug out again

Your contractors may not have been so daft as you think; pause a moment before you set about hacking apart all they did, and question whether your driver for doing so is actually correct. If Jane from reception needs to see a picture of John Smith with drivers license XY1234 to ID him, don't provide her with a shared drive full of everyone's pictures, and let her double click, drag and accidentally delete her way around the file system. Provide her with an app that looks in the db, gets the unintelligible but helpfully unique filename off disk and opens it for her to view. And make the file system read only to everyone other than the app, so that users can't break things

Comment: Thank  you for the suggestion. I wasn't intending to imply I thought they were daft. I only meant they either couldn't or wouldn't tell me how they did it. I suspect the latter.

What you've said makes sense. I was merely looking for the most simplistic transform. I considered concatenating a couple of the fields from the doc to avoid dupes. Still, I was considering exactly what you said as far as, importing them only to export them once. I believe your suggestion is not only much simpler but will be more effective. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: A shame that they were a bit awkward toward a former customer at the end; while they might not have wanted to lose your custom, the way the hand over seems to have been done might well have ensured that you wouldn't now reconsider becoming a customer in future! If you're looking to add something unique to avoid dupes I should point out that the names of the files are already rather unique.. The question would be more around *why* you want something human readable in the name; what processing are you doing with it that requires it it be human readable. Should that processing go in software?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The challenge is more annoying that I intended to trouble you all with so I tried to simplify my question. I may have overshot it a bit.

I updated my question for additional clarification.

Comment: Hopefully youre doing all this manipulating on a copy of your datastore rather than the real one! I read your edits; probably it doesn't affect anything I wrote above - I made an SQL that renames files, you've broken the folder structure (I wouldn't have flattened it) but at least the files are guid named, and the db contains the guids so it's not hopelessly broken; you just now need to amend the advice I gave to create an alternative naming stratey in your batch file. You can also have the SQL write HTML documents.. but i'm not really clear on your requirements for how the new vendor wants

Comment: the files. It would be bette rif you could decide this and then say exactly what you have (db + old file paths - got that part) and what you want (new file paths + html files called X and containing Y I *think*) - all of which can be prepared by careful SQL. I don't think you should try to encode info in the file names, and i definitely think you should leave the file names alone (as guids) and have the meta data in html/text/csv/whatever and refer to the file names (as guids)

Comment: Thank you again and I agree. Much of my ambiguity is a result of the limits of the information from the new vendor. The pandemic has us all in flux. Specifically, the new EMR vendor has discontinued phone support and abandoned their SLA purporting a 6-8 week lead time on case responses which appears to apply to onboarding support for new customers also. The lack of info is just one more of the hurdles that seem to be tauntingly daunting as of late. It's not personal and I'm sure they're doing what they can. I'm just trying to control the things I can and accept those I can't. Woosah!

Comment: I'll add more details to the question in a few minutes to see if you notice anything I'm overlooking. Thank you again. I appreciate the suggestions very much. I've spent the last 20 years as a network, systems, and solutions architect so this isn't my first rodeo in general. I just typically have dev resources on projects. I'm doing this for this company on a volunteer basis because they are frontline workers and due to the economic difficulties right now they can't afford to contract all of this out. We need these companies so I'm trying to do what I can, and some of what I can't, to help.

Comment: I said that to say that I'm definitely keeping redundant copies of everything. I built their infrastructure and I'm manipulating everything in the dev and stage platforms, not production.